# Hibernate Interceptor - Try-Catch T-SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, t-sql

I have the requirement to ignore primary key violations from SQL Server in my inserts. While there are several ways to accomplish this task, many of them have performance implications or are not feasible. I need to batch insert into a table and there is a possibility of duplicates.

To accomplish the task, I've written a Hibernate interceptor that intercepts `onPrepareStatement` and wraps the Hibernate generated SQL in a t-SQL TRY CATCH construct. The TRY CATCH looks for primary key violations and silences them. Below is my code for the interceptor.

```
private static final String FORMAT_TRY_CATCH = "BEGIN TRY %s END TRY\r\n" + "BEGIN CATCH\r\n" + "\r\n"
    + "DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000),\r\n" + "  @ErrorNumber INT,\r\n" + "  @ErrorSeverity INT,\r\n" + "  @ErrorState INT,\r\n"
    + "  @ErrorLine INT,\r\n" + "  @ErrorProcedure NVARCHAR(200) ;\r\n" + "\r\n"
    + "SELECT  @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),\r\n"
    + "        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(), @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE(),\r\n"
    + "        @ErrorProcedure = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '-') ;\r\n" + "\r\n"
    + "SELECT  @ErrorMessage = N'Error %%d, Level %%d, State %%d, Procedure %%s, Line %%d, ' +\r\n"
    + "        'Message: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() ;\r\n" + "     IF @ErrorNumber <> 2627\r\n" + "        BEGIN\r\n"
    + "RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, 1, @ErrorNumber, -- parameter: original error number.\r\n"
    + "  @ErrorSeverity, -- parameter: original error severity.\r\n" + "  @ErrorState, -- parameter: original error state.\r\n"
    + "  @ErrorProcedure, -- parameter: original error procedure name.\r\n"
    + "  @ErrorLine-- parameter: original error line number.\r\n" + "        ) ;\r\n" + "       END\r\n" + "END CATCH;";

@Override
public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
    if (sql.toLowerCase().startsWith("insert")) {
        return String.format(FORMAT_TRY_CATCH, sql);
    }
    return sql;
}
```

The interceptor works except that when there is a primary key constraint violation the statement returns 0 affected rows. Hibernate has a check that throws an exception if the number of affected rows doesn't match the expected number of rows. I can work around the issue by executing a dummy t-SQL statement that returns one affected row.

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE (col1 int)
INSERT INTO @dummy values (1)
```

This dummy logic will decrease the performance when there is a primary key constraint violation. Is there a better performing dummy script, or a better way to catch primary key constraint violations?

Note: doing a select before each insert is not acceptable for performance reasons. I cannot recreate my SQL's primary key to turn on IGNORE_DUP_KEY.